# Using display:flex on almost everything

Tags: css, flexbox

Should flex always be used in lieu of floats or other display modes (except inline)? Is this true, or is there something the others can do that flex cannot?

Example webpage:

[image]

All the red-stroked boxes can be flex containers (not just flex items). Some oriented vertically, some horizontally. Some flex items with flex-grow and flex-shrink, some without.

So, considering that flex can handle all that and that it has other advantages (order and flexible dimensions), is there any reason to use floats and other old techniques?

Comment: This is a bad question because it gives no situation to work with. If you're meaning that flex is the only display one should use, that is an opinionated question not fit for SO

Comment: ok i will post an example

Comment: Floats shouldn't have been used for layouts in the first place. They're still useful for proper floating of images. The `float` property simply doesn't apply (rightfully) to a flex'd item.

Comment: So you are saying that I'm right?

Comment: position , float , display are different ways to control flow of element at screen or print medias . What matters is to use the appropriate, and appropriate is the one that media and develloper handle the best.just M.O.H.O.   i.e.surfing in IE8 upon flex rules ....

Comment: I've got a work in progress flex LESS solution with table layout fallback, which utilizes modernizr. http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/Kterj

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flexbox comes to improve existing layouts. Float is still the only option to do what it does, there's no flexbox alternative for it. You can see flexbox as "improved tables". It shares many concepts with them (but it isn't a complete alternative)

`display:flex` can't even replace `block`, because a `display:flex` is actually a `block` itself; `flex` affects its children not the way it is laid out itself

same as a `display:inline-block` element. it is laid out like an `inline` element, but its contents are laid out as they were in a `display:block` element

you can have `display:flex` on almost everything, except on text blocks, like paragraphs and headings, or any other text string. they should be contained in a block element, otherwise browsers will do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/56fHY/

what you can also see from this example, is that even if `<b>` is `display:inline`, since its container is `display:flex`, it is forced to be `display:block`

you also still need `float:` as I already said

you also may need `inline-flex`: a typical use case are elements such as widgets that should work both when placed in a `display:block` paragraph and when used in a `display:flex` container

you still need also `display:table` or `<table>`s because flexbox can't cover all their features. for example in order to make grids with flexbox you have to specify dimensions (via width/height/flex-basis) while with tables dimensions are calculated implicitly (eg the width of the cells in a column are equal to the larger cell in the column); you can for example simulate `colspan` but not `rowspan`) http://jsfiddle.net/xDLvg/

and of course you still need `display:inline` elements, for bold and other text-level styling

hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @wesabi answer who already tackled many aspects of the question:

- Compatibility is IE10+
- `-flex-wrap` is compatible with IE11+ and Firefox 28+ (and Chrome 21+ Safari 6.1+, less problematic). Way too soon to rely on that for my clients.
- without `-flex-wrap` ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fhoij), just remove flex-wrap to see what it's like without), you have a HUGE constraint: all your elements must be **siblings**.
  If your elements are siblings and you're designing an adaptive layout, they're either stacked vertically (say, with a 320px wide viewport) or horizontally (say, with a 1280+ px viewport). There's no way of an intermediate layout of 2 rows of 2 columns with 4 siblings... You then have to go the *inception-way* and do complicate things instead of floating elements with the usual clear, clearfix or else `inline-block` or use table layout in one resolution, floats in another and flex in yet another resolution.
- there are other properties of the spec that are still not implemented
- how'd you use flex in the few cases where you're using absolute/fixed positioning? Modals to begin with, banner of text over an image, dropdowns, etc
- another use case: `p:first-letter { float: left; font-size: 1.5em; }`
- grid layout (IE10+ only, sigh) is way more powerful (and opened to abuse from an accessibility point of view because, well, it's powerful)

tl;dr flex has a **bright** future for layout (*) (and present in Media Query at-rules except in IE9) but it won't make any other way of doing layouts completely useless, just replace some or many of their uses.

(*) in a post-IE8+ world, assuming IE9 will have disappeared before IE8 because XP limits IE to IE8 but IE on Vista/7/8 can be upgraded beyond IE8 and IE9

Comment: I actually never knew about flex-wrap until your post and didn't feel like I was missing it

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox on everything but you really shouldn't. Flexbox is a new layout algorithm for laying out complex web pages/applications, but he also have it disadventages(temporarily the most slower layout).
Basically flexbox is the most best for smaller page components and UI elements. New Grid layout is more suitable for overall page layout. They play well together and in future we will use them together.

Comment: I agree.  Lots of places I've seen more problems in mobile layouts where devs used flexbox, but a bootstrap grid would have been fine and more consistent behavior across all breakpoints.